# Sudo - Module Not Found

Tags: python, import, sudo

I have a python app that imports:

```
import pyttsx3
```

If I execute the app using

```
sudo python3 mprobot.py
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mprobot.py", line 11, in <module>
    import pyttsx3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyttsx3'
```

If I execute using:

```
python3 mprobot.py
```

It works fine.

Curious of why one works and the other doesn't

Comment: why do you need `sudo`?

Comment: And if you use the full path to `mprobot.py`?

Comment: do you have 2 python versions installed?

Comment: i used to have the same problem when i had both 3.6 and 3.8 installed

Comment: You don\'t need to use sudo

Comment: I understand I don’t need Sudo if I run it under my own user ID. I need to run it under another user, Shairport-Sync.  When  I run it there I get a permission denied error. I figured if I run it with sudo it would resolve the problem.

Sashank. - yes I have 2 versions on python: 2.7 & 3.7.3. If I uninstall 2.7, will this resolve I problem?